# Avoid discovering services and characteristics on a reconnect in CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am working on a CoreBluetooth manager app for an iPhone.  To be able to reconnect to a previously discovered CBPeripheral, I save the UUID of the peripheral (in CoreData) and then call CBCentralManager's retrievePeripherals:.  My didRetrievePeripherals: callback is called and I can connect, etc.  So far so good.

Since I am reconnecting to a peripheral that I already know about, I would like to avoid discovering its services and characteristics.  So I save the UUIDs of the services and characteristics (again in CoreData, along with the peripheral's UUID) when I first connect.

But I cannot use these UUIDs to read or write the characteristics because the CBPeripheral's readValueForCharacteristic: or writeValueForCharacteristic: take a CBCharacteristic as a parameter, and there is no API to construct a CBCharacteristic instance.

Is there any way to avoid discovering services and characteristics while reconnecting with a previously known peripheral?

Comment: Hello, as you save the UUID of known devices in CoreData, couldn't you just save a data structure for each device containing the services and characteristics they implement ?

Comment: The services and characteristics of a device are identified by UUIDs, which I save.  But I cannot save instances of CBService and CBCharacteristic in CoreData because they are not derived from NSManagedObject - at least, I don't know how I could do it.  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Ok I know understand your question. I think you'll have to do with discoverCharacteristics:forService: using the UUIDs...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now, but I was trying avoid that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mezulu, you want to use an encrypted/paired link – then iOS will do the caching for you. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870948/reconnect-a-cbperipheral-faster/16051170#16051170).

Comment: thanks for this response.  I wasn't aware that iOS 6 had introduced caching of services and characteristics.  This is what I was looking for.